# Programatically create items in Infopath form library With Content Type in SharePoint 2013

Tags: infopath

Having Infopath form library with different content types published to Form Library.
I have to create forms in Infopath form library with content type ID in SharePoint 2013 with Button click event.

Kindly provide the code to start the requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please someone provide the solution to get the requirement done.

Comment: I didn't have the correct approach to fulfill the requirement, can someone provide insights on the requirement. Thanks in advance.